# Sieve of Eratosthenes with nested for loops

Tags: python-3.x, list, append, primes

This is a very simple question about python. I was trying to get a list of prime numbers so I tried

```
primes = [2]

for i in primes:
   for j in range(50):
      if j%i != 0:
         primes.append(j)

print(primes)
```

But it just goes into an indefinite loop.

Comment: well you are appending to `primes`  and running a loop over it, what did you expect to happen

Comment: work it out using pen and paper, do you think you are getting the expected results?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I've only been using python for seven hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the results are:
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
23
25
27
29
31
33
35...

Comment: @XxJames07- I'm not getting any results

Comment: thats because you have to print them (when you append to 'primes')

Comment: @XxJames07- When I print(j) I get a bunch of random numbers between 0 and 50. Most aren't prime

Comment: yea i just provided the first results, when it reaches 50 it includes some other numbers and it goes on forever

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over a `list` and appending to it that will make that infinite process as the iteration just takes the index but you can put an end by defining the limit value

There are lots of methods to achieve that, but i would suggest to just break if the number is bigger than the `limit`:

```
primes = [2]
limit = 40
for i in primes:
   if primes[-1]>limit:break
   for j in range(50):
      if j%i != 0:
         primes.append(j)

print(primes)
```

Before that, you should know what you are doing, an advice is to first do your calculations on paper and then code them.

Your code provides different results as they are not prime, first come up with an algorithm or search online.

using the provided [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Pseudocode) you should be able to use the pseudocode to come up with one on your own, here is an example:

```
from math import isqrt
limit = 40
primes = [True]*limit
primes[0] = False
primes[1] = False
for i in range(2,isqrt(limit-1)+1):
    if primes[i]:
        for j in range(i*i,limit,i):
            primes[j] = False
from numpy import where
print(list(where(primes)[0]))
# >>> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]
```

Comment: The algorithm goes like this: start with the first prime [2], then check if 2 divides 3 if not add to list [2, 3]. Next check if 2 or 3 divides 4, 2 does so move on. Check if 2 or 3 divides 5, they don't so add 5: [2,3,5]. Make your way through the numbers that way checking if any primes less than n divides n. If yes move on, if no add n to the list and carry on.

Comment: The code doesn't work. It still goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Now it should work

Comment: My laptop fan is going crazy and there's no output...

Comment: Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

Comment: Make the limit less than 50

Comment: It worked! but it's picking up composite numbers
[2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, ....]

Comment: Your question was on how to not make an infinite loop with your code right?

Comment: It was how to get algorithm to work. I nearly mentioned what the problem was. I still can't get a list of primes.

Comment: You want `isqrt(limit) + 1` instead of `isqrt(limit)`. (Try the current code with `limit=50` and you'll see that `49` is being identified as prime.) Though actually, `isqrt(limit-1) + 1` is enough.